# Python adding multiple items to a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, append

I have to write a program that asks the user to enter their shopping list, it should ask them to enter their first item for their list and to enter 'END' when they have entered all of their items.

This is my code so far:

```
#Welcome
name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Welcome %s to your shopping list" %name)
#Adding to the list
shoppingList = []
shoppingList.append = input(print("Please enter the first item of your shopping list and type END when you have entered all of your items: "))
length = len(shoppingList)
#Output
print("Your shopping list is", length, "items long")
shoppingList.sort
print(shoppingList)
```

I'm not to sure how to fix the adding to the list second, could you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append is a function, so you should be calling it like this.

```
shoppingList.append("Bread")
```

However, in order to add more than one item, you'll need some kind of a loop.

```
while True:
    new_item = input(print("Please enter an item of your shopping list and type END when you have entered all of your items: "))
    if new_item == "END": break
    shoppingList.append(new_item)
```

This loop appends each string that is not "END" to the list. When "END" is entered, the loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning to the `append` method. What you want to do is assign to the actual list:

```
shoppingList = [item for item in input(print("....")).split()][:-1]
```

The `[:-1]` there is to drop the `END`. Or you can make it a filter

```
shoppingList = [item for item in input(print("....")).split() if item != 'END']
```

Comment: If I use either method, each character is printed separately, i.e milk becomes 'm','i','l','k'. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: @barry this will not work,as for is iterating over the input string first

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to add `.split()`

Answer (score 0):

add while and check for `End`:

```
shopingList = []
end =''
while end.lower() != 'end':
    item = input("Please enter the item of youi shopping list and type END when you have entered all of your items: ")
    shopingList.append(item)
    end = item
```

There is no need of `print` statement inside `input`

in the above code, i am checking if the user enters `end` it will come of the while loop.
varible `item` will store the user input and append it to the shopingList, `end` variable is updated with user item as in while `end` variable is compared with string 'end'

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm relatively new to python, is there a more simple way of doing this?

Comment: I just retried it, I must have typed something wrong, it works now. Thank you!